# Rewrite in htaccess trying to do a transparent redirect: rules with [R=301] works but not [L]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some rewriteRule in my .htaccess. 
I'm trying to do a transparent redirect for all urls starting with _ (like: `http://mydomain/_hello` to `http://mydomain/object/hello`). Here's what I tried:
`RewriteRule ^_([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ object/$1 [L]` but it gives me a "Page not found" error.
When I change to [R=301,L] (not [R=301]), it works but the url changes in the browser.

My full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^_([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php/object/view_by_alias/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I really don't understand what's happening?

Comment: Directly entering `http://mydomain/object/hello` in browser loads it fine?

Comment: It loads fine with the full url but the url in the browser changes too like a R=301.

Comment: Actually I didn't understand your question. Directly entering the url in the browser works, off course. My previous answer was about entering the full url in the rewriterule like that: `RewriteRule ^_([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ http://mydomain/object/$1 [L]` In that case the redirection works but the url of the browser changes.

Comment: ok Is this some kind of CMS/PHP framework you are using here?

Comment: yes I just want to add a shorten url rule

Comment: I didn't get your comment. But try: `RewriteRule ^_([\w-]+)$ object/view_by_alias/$1 [L]`

Comment: I still got the same behavior with you last suggestion `^_([\w-]+)$` .

Comment: I tried to use only alias redirection but it still gives me the "Page not found" error: 
`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/object/view_by_alias/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Add `Options -Multiviews` above the rules
- Change back to `[L]`

Also, note that you don't need `QSA` since you're not adding anything to the query string.

Comment: still no luck with that zx81.

Comment: Trying `RewriteRule ^_([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/object/view_by_alias/$1 [L]` behave like a R=301 ... I really don't understand.